# How to produce a file encoded in Mac OS Roman

Tags: shell, character-encoding

Inside a bash script I have a line that creates and then inside a loop, append strings to a text file, something like

```
echo $myTextString >> file.txt
```

I need this final file to be formatted using **Western (Mac OS Roman)**.

The file does not exist when the script starts, so the first appending line will create the file. Is there a way to make the file be that format or convert it at the end to this Mac OS Roman format? How do I do that inside the bash script?

Comment: My `iconv -l` do not list no similar encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) character set conversion GNU utility.
Here's an example:

`iconv --from-code=UTF-8 --to-code=MAC  INPUTFILE > OUTPUTFILE`

where `INPUTFILE`and `OUTPUTFILE` are the names of your original and converted file (which may be the same). You'd alaso need to substitute `UTF-8` by your native encoding, if it's not Unicode, and `MAC` may not be exactly the encoding you're looking for: `iconv -l` gives you a list of possible encodings to choose from (in my system none of them corresponds in an obvious way to "Western (Mac OS Roman)".